# Method GetInfo in WebSerial API? Is there another way to get device infos?

Tags: google-chrome, serial-port, webusb

I'm using the Web Serial API to connect two different scales. They send the weight data in different ways, so I'm trying to get the serialport metadata from them (vendorId etc) because I want to detect which scale is connected. The "getInfo()" method does not work because it is undefined in the Serialport Object.

```
[Exposed=(DedicatedWorker,Window), SecureContext]
interface SerialPortInfo {
  maplike<DOMString, DOMString?>;
};
```

This is the interface for the metadata but I don't even know, how to use it.

My sources: https://wicg.github.io/serial/#dom-serialportinfo

Answer (score 0):

The method is declared a little strangely in that version of the specification. You can treat the return value as a plan object. If the port is a USB device then it will have `usbVendorId` and `usbProductId` properties which are the metadata you are interested in.

Comment: It is a USB device. The one scale is a cdc device, the other is vendor-specific. When I want to call port.getInfo(), it says that the method does not exist... How can I get the return values?

Comment: getInfo() was implemented in Chrome 85.0.4183.0.

Comment: When is it possible to filter by vendorId ?

Comment: i can't access to the devices on linux. Is there a udev- rule to create?

Comment: Do you have an advice?

Comment: To filter by vendor ID call `navigator.serial.requestPort({filters: {usbVendorId: <the vendor ID>}})`.